# how to refund sale amount in paypal php rest api Sandbox mode

Tags: php, paypal

How to refund sale amount in paypal php api in sandbox mode i am getting error as following error.

```
Array
(
    [TIMESTAMP] => 2018%2d02%2d05T05%3a25%3a03Z
    [CORRELATIONID] => 4dce78895e2a8
    [ACK] => Failure
    [VERSION] => 94
    [BUILD] => 43477490
    [L_ERRORCODE0] => 10009
    [L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Transaction%20refused
    [L_LONGMESSAGE0] => You%20can%20not%20refund%20this%20type%20of%20transaction
    [L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error
)
```

please help out
Thanks

Comment: "You%20can%20not%20refund%20this%20type%20of%20transaction"

Comment: @rtfm do you have any solution ???

Answer (score 0):

The transaction which you are trying to refund is showing the status as Unclaimed. That means the payment is not completed yet. This is the reason for getting the error. The payment is in unclaimed status due to currency setting and waiting for your accept. You will need to login to seller sandbox account for accepting the payment. Once you accept the payment it will get completed after this you can refund the payment.

Comment: Hi @PP_Punna thanks for reply but could you please show me the steps for the sandbox seller account settings which you asking me to change it will helpful to me and i will get result because i made to much try on this point since last 15 days,

thanks

Comment: Login to https://www.sandbox.paypal.com, Go to Profile --> Profile and Settings --> Click on update next to Block Payments, now choose Yes under "Allow payments sent to me in a currency I do not hold". Now run another new sandbox test payment. The payment will complete immediately. After this, you will be able to run refund successfully.

Comment: Thank you very much its working as you said payment shows unclaimed and after changing settings and making refund i get response

Array
(
    [REFUNDTRANSACTIONID] => 450995331X700525X
    [FEEREFUNDAMT] => 0%2e58
    [GROSSREFUNDAMT] => 20%2e00
    [NETREFUNDAMT] => 19%2e42
    [CURRENCYCODE] => GBP
    [TOTALREFUNDEDAMOUNT] => 20%2e00
    [TIMESTAMP] => 2018%2d02%2d07T05%3a20%3a42Z
    [CORRELATIONID] => a1f6c4ea86aa7
    [ACK] => Success
    [VERSION] => 94
    [BUILD] => 43477490
    [REFUNDSTATUS] => Delayed
    [PENDINGREASON] => echeck
)
but  [REFUNDSTATUS] => Delayed